# What is the difference between “assert”, “expect”, and “should” in Chai?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

What is the difference between `assert`, `expect`, and `should`? When to use what?

```js
assert.equal(3, '3', '== coerces values to strings');
    
var foo = 'bar';
    
expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
    
foo.should.equal('bar');
```

Answer (score 313):

The differences are [documented there](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#differences).

The three interfaces present different styles of performing assertions. Ultimately, they perform the same task. Some users prefer one style over the other. This being said, there are also a couple technical considerations worth highlighting:

1. The `assert` and `expect` interfaces do not modify `Object.prototype`, whereas `should` does. So they are a better choice in an environment where you cannot or do not want to change `Object.prototype`.
2. The `assert` and `expect` interfaces support custom messages just about everywhere. For instance:

   ```js
    assert.isTrue(foo, "foo should be true");
    expect(foo, "foo should be true").to.be.true;
   ```

The message "foo should be true" will be output together with the failed assertion if the assertion fails. You don't get the opportunity to set a custom message with the `should` interface.

(Historical note: for a long time this answer stated that to get a custom message with `expect`, you'd have to use a workaround. [Aurélien Ribon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/294918/aur%c3%a9lien-ribon) informed me that passing a message to `expect` as a second parameter works. Consequently, there is no need for a workaround. I've not been able to find which version of Mocha started providing support for this message, nor have I been able to find which version of the documentation documented it for the first time.)

Note that `assert.isTrue(foo)`, `expect(foo).to.be.true` and `foo.should.be.true` all output the following if you do not use a custom message, and `foo === 1`:

```
    AssertionError: expected 1 to be true
```

So while the `expect` and `should` interface are nicer to *read*, it is not like one interface is more naturally informative than the other when an assertion fails. This message, which is identical for all three interfaces, does not tell you *what* exactly you were testing, only that the value you got was `1` but you wanted `true`. If you want to know what you were testing, you need to add a message.

Comment: Note that you can also do `expect(foo).to.equal(true, "foo should be true");`

Comment: I cannot get any custom message to  appear with `expect`, using the latest version of mocha

Comment: @Mirko The version of Mocha is not what is critical here. Are you using the latest Chai?

Comment: Same for me, on a vanilla express (4.16.3), mocha (5.1.1), chai (4.1.2), chai-http (4.0.0) project. The custom message does not appear anywhere when ran with the command ``mocha`` and getting a test failure.

Answer (score 32):

I hope this simple examples makes their differences clear

**Assert**

```
var assert = require('chai').assert
const foo = 'bar'
const beverages = { tea: [ 'chai', 'matcha', 'oolong' ] };

assert.typeOf(foo, 'string'); // without optional message
assert.typeOf(foo, 'string', 'foo is a string'); // with optional message
assert.equal(foo, 'bar', 'foo equal `bar`');
assert.lengthOf(foo, 3, 'foo`s value has a length of 3');
assert.lengthOf(beverages.tea, 3, 'beverages has 3 types of tea');
```

In all cases, the assert style allows you to include an optional message as the last parameter in the assert statement. These will be included in the error messages should your assertion not pass.

**Note**
`expect` and `should` uses chainable language to construct assertions, but they differ in the way an assertion is initially constructed. In the case of `should`, there are also some caveats and additional tools to overcome the caveats.

**Expect**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect
const foo = 'bar'
const beverages = { tea: [ 'chai', 'matcha', 'oolong' ] };
expect(foo).to.be.a('string');
expect(foo).to.equal('bar');
expect(foo).to.have.lengthOf(3);
expect(beverages).to.have.property('tea').with.lengthOf(3);
```

`expect` allows you to include arbitrary messages to prepend to any failed assertions that might occur.

```
var answer = 43;

// AssertionError: expected 43 to equal 42.
expect(answer).to.equal(42);

// AssertionError: topic [answer]: expected 43 to equal 42.
expect(answer, 'topic [answer]').to.equal(42);
```

This comes in handy when being used with non-descript topics such as booleans or numbers.

**Should**

The `should` style allows for the same chainable assertions as the expect interface, however it extends each object with a should property to start your chain. This style has some issues when used with Internet Explorer, so be aware of browser compatibility.

```
var should = require('chai').should() //actually call the function
const foo = 'bar'
const beverages = { tea: [ 'chai', 'matcha', 'oolong' ] };

foo.should.be.a('string');
foo.should.equal('bar');
foo.should.have.lengthOf(3);
beverages.should.have.property('tea').with.lengthOf(3);
```

**Differences between expect and should**

First of all, notice that the `expect` require is just a reference to the `expect` function, whereas with the `should` require, the function is being executed.

```
var chai = require('chai')
const expect = chai.expect
const should = chai.should();
```

The **expect** interface provides a function as a starting point for chaining your language assertions. It works on node.js and in all browsers.

The **should** interface extends Object.prototype to provide a single getter as the starting point for your language assertions. It works on node.js and in all modern browsers except Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but there is also a huge difference between an assert and an expect in terms of code running behavior.
Assert is supposed to stop the program on error.
Expect is not.